# How to change the price of a variable product in the cart depending on the already selected variation in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Help, please, to solve a difficult problem. There is a store on Woocommerce. Variable products have been created that have the attribute "Select weight, kg" with values (example of one product):

0.25 kg - $34

0.5 kg - $66

1 kg - $123

2 kg - $246

3 kg - $342

4 kg - $440

6 kg - $618

8 kg - $784

10 kg - $940

The client, for example, made the following order (of the same product, but different variations) -

10 kg - $940

1 kg - $123

How to make the price of 1 kg recalculated in the basket - 940 / 10 = $94? Or, for example, the client ordered -

6 kg - $618

2 kg - $246

How to make the price of 2 kg recalculated in the basket - 618 / 6 * 2 = $206?

I tried this code

```
function recalculate_variable_product_price($cart)
{
  if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
    return;
  }

  foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
    if ($cart_item['variation_id'] > 0) {
      $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
      $product_id   = $cart_item['product_id'];
      $weight       = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_weight', true);
      $quantity     = $cart_item['quantity'];

      if ($weight > 0) {
        $new_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price() / floatval($weight) * $quantity;

        // Устанавливаем пересчитанную цену
        $cart_item['data']->set_price($new_price);
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'recalculate_variable_product_price', 10, 1);
```

but it doesn't seem to be what I need